# External image not displaying in Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am developing an app with VS 2019 for Windows, using Xamarin (version 3.6).  My app loads images from an external source (my web server) and displays them to the user.

I built and released the Android app about a month ago, having no problems with any of the external images.  Since then, I've been making updates to the project to get ready for an iOS release.

A couple days ago, I ran the project on my two android phones (both of which updated themselves recently) and now the app does not display the external images on either phone.

I am referencing image source by http, not https (makes no difference either way).

More information: When I install the app from the Google Play store (which I deployed there about a month ago), everything works fine.  It's only when I try to debug from Visual Studio that the images fail to display.

Has anyone run into a similar problem?

Comment: I have what I believe is the proper permission (INTERNET) set in the manifest

Comment: @Jeff,You mean that the image can not display on android device when debug in Visual Studio, can you share your http url here, I will help you to test at my side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This apparently was caused by updating my Visual Studio version.  I had been using VS 2019 for Windows, and had been on an interim version (As of December, they were still in beta, I believe).

I found a suggestion in another thread to update to the last version of Xamarin Forms.  I did this (version 4.4....).  I had to go through some pain with the Android support libraries (apparently they are no longer needed or supported, as of December 2019).  Once I got everything to compile, my images started showing up again.

There are lots of suggestions on various sites for problems similar to this, including some saying to use TLS 1.2 and Native HttpClient, but for me the Xamarin update worked.  A bonus -- I got the new XAML hot-load feature, which is pretty cool.

Comment: It seems that you have solved your issue by yourself, please remember to mark your reply as answer, it is beneficial to other community members who face the same issue, thanks.